# How to get rid of & in cases environment but still get the same space in the surroundings

Tags: spacing, amsmath, cases

[Recently I asked a question on chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49159326#49159326) but [I was told](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49159639#49159639) that I have to ask it on the main site, so here I am.

I am using `cases` environment to create multiple system of equations separated by a symbol e.g. `\equiv`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cases}
x+y=2,\\x=2
\end{cases}
\equiv
\begin{cases}
2+y=2,\\x=2
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: What I have done]

However, as you can see there is a huge space between the end of the first `cases` and the `\equiv`. [This is due of the absence of `&` symbol in `cases`](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49159458#49159458), but I do not want to add this symbol to fill the space. So a manual, inefficient and even incorrect solution that I found was to add negative space, let's say add 5/6 `\!`'s just before `\equiv`.

If I add `5` negative spaces then there is more space on one side than on the other:

[image: What happens if we add five !]

If I add `6` negative spaces then the same thing happens as before:

[image: The same thing happens]

More than `6` or less than `5` will cause a worse output.

I would like that, keeping the same format of system of equations, **there would be a homogeneous space on both sides of each `cases`**. Is it possible?

Thanks!!

P.S. I would also like to know if in a system of equations you would separate each equation by a `,` except in the last equation that appears, that is, in the one below (unless there is a text that continues with the reading or that ends the sentence). Does AMS Style Guide say something about this?

Comment: If we use `\left\{\begin{array}{l}...\end{array}\right.` instead of `cases` then the space between the left brace and the system of equations should also be corrected, in addition to solve the problem of space between the environment and any consequent symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `aligned`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{system}
  {\[\left\lbrace\aligned}
  {\endaligned\right.\]\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
Example:
\begin{system}
&x+y=2\\&x=2
\end{system}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I end up with `\[\begin{system}&x+y=2\\&x=2\end{system}\]` since I have more than one `system` in one line, but this is great and simple, thank you!

Comment: I am getting "Missing control sequence inserted" when I use `'` and write all in one line: try `\[\begin{system}&a'=2\\&b'=2\end{system}\]`. To solve this, I have to insert a blank space between `\begin{system}` and `\end{system}`, so suppose that `\\ ` represents a new line i.e. an "Enter", so I have to do `\[\begin{system}\\&a'=2\\&b'=2\\\end{system}\]`. I am writing a lot of these systems in my document, so I want to write it inline in my source code. How can we fix that?

Comment: @manooooh as requested the `\[` is inside the definition of system so of course you can not put `\begin{system}` in math, that would be `\[\[\begin{ligned}` with two `\[` .

Comment: I need to write `\begin{system}&a+b\\&-a-b\end{system}`, but the minus sign is shifted to the right (because it is a binary operator, as expected). How could we fix this: using `\!-a-b`?

Comment: There is a problem when adding `\usepackage{mathtools}`.

Comment: @manooooh "a problem" is not a very useful comment, what error did you get? I just replaced  `amsmath` by `mathtools` in the above and got identical output.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the intercolumn space and also the null delimiter space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{system}
 {%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{}}%
 }
 {%
  \endarray
  \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{system}
x+y=2,\\x=2
\end{system}
\equiv
\begin{system}
2+y=2,\\x=2
\end{system}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have doubts your readers will understand what you mean here.

Comment: This is just what I wanted, thank you!! Could you help me in deciding if a comma is OK to separate different equations inside a `system` environment (unless there is a text that continues with the reading or that ends the sentence) like I said on the P.S., please?

Comment: @manooooh I wouldn't use it

Comment: Ok. If the system of equations ends the sentence, would you write a dot in the end of the last equation (from your answer, `x=2.\end{system}`)?

Comment: @manooooh I'd avoid ending the sentence with a system. It's easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{L}{16pt}
\begin{document}
\[
\biggl\{\Centerstack[l]{x+y=2,\\x=2}
\equiv
\biggl\{\Centerstack[l]{2+y=2,\\x=2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good. However, I would not like to modify any format except the spacing. Thanks!

Comment: @manooooh I understand.  I put it out there for others to consider as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `systeme` package.

The grouped equations in your example are really systems of equations and *not* cases.  And, as egreg says, someone trying to grasp the meaning from your code may be confused by the misattribution.

Comment: Yes... you are right, it can lead to confusion. I do not accept your answer as I value more saving to load a package than to load it, but thanks!