# Using numcases with cases

Tags: math-mode, equations, labels, cases

I have an equation like so:

```
   \[ \begin{cases}
         Eqn1 &= 0,\\
         Eqn2 &= 0,
      \end{cases} \iff
      \begin{cases}
         Eqn3 &= 0,\\
         Eqn4 &= 0,\\
         Eqn5 &= 0.
      \end{cases}
   \]
```

This works all nice and good, however, I would like to numerate the "right side" of those (in this case 3) equations. Naively, I thought I could use numcases for the second "block", but of course this is good as numcases for some reason cannot be between `\[\]` or the-like.
Is there a way to do this?

Patrick

Comment: Where did you get numcases?  It isn't in amsmath or mathtools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your readers will understand what the numbers refer to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq} % also loads amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[
  left=
    {\begin{cases}
    Eqn1 = 0,\\
    Eqn2 = 0,
    \end{cases}} \iff
    \empheqlbrace
]{align}
  Eqn3 &= 0,\\
  Eqn4 &= 0,\\
  Eqn5 &= 0.
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

The additional braces around `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}` are needed because there are commas in the code. Note that you shouldn't use `&=` inside `cases` (thanks to Bernard for noting).

[image]

Comment: The spacing of `=` is not correct in the cases envritonment.

Comment: @Bernard Right. Fixed with acknowledgment.

Comment: If the OP wants to get a proper space between system of equations I suggest follow this @egreg's answer: [How to get rid of & in cases environment but still get the same space in the surroundings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476123/152550).

Answer (score 2):

To disambiguate to which equalities the numbers refer to, one may use the`adjustwidth` environment, to have the numbers closer. Also, one can nest `cases` in the left-side argument of `numcases`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{6em}{6em}
\begin{numcases}
    {\begin{cases}
    Eqn1 = 0,\\
    Eqn2 = 0,
    \end{cases} \iff}
  Eqn3 = 0,\\
  Eqn4 = 0,\\
  Eqn5 = 0.
\end{numcases}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]